# Elixir :invalid_child_spec for supervised process. Can't figure out why

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I'm working on implementing a supervisor for the first time and I'm running into issues that I can't figure out from the documentation. Specifically, when I try to start my process using `SlowRamp.flood` I get `{:error, {:invalid_child_spec, []}}`.

This is a very simple application and was made using mix new slow_ramp --sup.

The main file in `./lib/slow_ramp.ex` is:

```
defmodule SlowRamp do
  use Application

  # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(SlowRamp.Flood, [])
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: SlowRamp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  def flood do
    Supervisor.start_child(SlowRamp.Supervisor, [])
  end
end
```

My child function / file is in `./lib/SlowRamp/flood.ex` and looks like this:

```
defmodule SlowRamp.Flood do
  def start_link do
    Task.start_link(fn -> start end)
  end

  defp start do
    receive do
      {:start, host, caller} ->
        send caller, System.cmd("cmd", ["opt"])
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on

```
Supervisor.start_child(SlowRamp.Supervisor, [])
```

You need a valid child specification, like:

```
def flood do
  import Supervisor.Spec
  Supervisor.start_child(SlowRamp.Supervisor, worker(SlowRamp.Flood, [], [id: :foo]))
end
```

Thats the reason its telling that the child spec is invalid

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood how that worked. Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Perfect answer. We are relying too much on Erlang supervisors here... we could have better error messages and one day we will (hopefully!).

Answer (score 0):

As of elixir 1.5, you can now define a `child_spec` to solve this as well.

Inside of `SlowRamp.Flood`, add a function like this:

```
defmodule SlowRamp.Flood do
  def child_spec(arg) do
    %{
     id: __MODULE__,
     start: {__MODULE__, :start_link, [arg]},
     type: :worker
   }
  end
  # Rest of your code here
end
```

Afterwards, your existing `start_link` should work.